# Python script not running in ec2 instance

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have a shell script that I am running using user data in my ec2 instance. The shell script contains a python script which splits a video into frames. However this python script is not able to import the required modules even though i have installed them in the instance. I am getting th e following error in the cloud-init-output.log file ater i boot the instance.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "frame_splitter.py", line 4, in <module>
    import cv2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'
Cloud-init v. 20.4.1-0ubuntu1~18.04.1 running 'modules:final' at Fri, 19 Mar 2021 11:09:20 +0000. Up 17.64 seconds.
```

The python script runs perfectly when I execute it directly. It is just not running when I run it thorugh the shell script from the user data.

The user data code is as follows

```
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="//"
MIME-Version: 1.0

--//
Content-Type: text/cloud-config; charset="us-ascii"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="cloud-config.txt"

#cloud-config
cloud_final_modules:
- [scripts-user, always]

--//
Content-Type: text/x-shellscript; charset="us-ascii"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="userdata.txt"

#!/bin/sh
cd /home/ubuntu
sh ./panorama.sh
```

There are 3 modules that i need for the code to run (glob,cv2 and os)

EDIT

I have added the line
pip3 install --target ./package opencv-python
in the user data after cd/home/ubuntu

I have the following error in the log file.

```
Collecting opencv-python
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bb/08/9dbc183a3ac6baa95fabf749ddb531bd26256edfff5b6c2195eca26258e9/opencv-python-4.5.1.48.tar.gz (88.3MB)
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-xzoveeew/opencv-python/setup.py", line 10, in <module>
        import skbuild
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'skbuild'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-xzoveeew/opencv-python/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "frame_splitter.py", line 4, in <module>
    import cv2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'
```

Comment: You've already asked that, and this question does not provide any new details. What exactly is `panorama.sh`? how did you install all these libraries in the first place? What have you changed/tried since last time you asked this? Can you provide minimal reproducible example of the issue?

Comment: @Marcin I have added the new error in the edit

Comment: your script runs as `root`, not `ubuntu`. So installing everything under `ubuntu` user will not work. Install these libraries at system level using `apt install`.

Comment: my suggestion. add `which pip` as a command inside your `./panorama.sh`. it will tell you which python executable it is using. suggestion 2) .  inside your python script `import sys`  and then `print(sys.path)`. this is where the python is looking for modules. these commands should give you enough hints to find what you are doing wrong.